# Surge install mac osx

Tags: node.js, macos, npm, surge.sh

i trying to deploy fornt-end site on [Surge](https://surge.sh/help/getting-started-with-surge) but when i try to install surge client into osx with

> npm install --global surge

i get following error message

> no such file or directory, open '/Users/mac/package.json'

Inside Surge getting started [page](https://surge.sh/help/getting-started-with-surge) there is no reference to this error.

My nodejs version is 8.9.4
Some one had same problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looking [here](https://medium.com/surge-sh/introducing-surge-the-cdn-for-front-end-developers-b4a50a61bcfc) i found the problem.

So instead of using

```
npm install --global surge
```

i should use

```
npm install --g surge
```